# Cannot show error message "No result Found" in php-ajax-live-search-with-multiple-value

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I followed this tutorial on https://www.webslesson.info/2019/03/php-ajax-live-search-with-multiple-value.html

Everything works well, after hosting on my local computer. Except when I search data not available on my database , I want to get error message " No result found on this table" .
Please check the code.

You can check demo here as well, http://demo.webslesson.info/bootstrap-tags-input-with-php/. "No result found error does not pop up when we search invalid value.

Index.php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Live Data Search using Multiple Tag in PHP with Ajax</title>  
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput-typeahead.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <style>
  .bootstrap-tagsinput {
   width: 100%;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
   <h2 align="center">Live Data Search using Multiple Tag in PHP with Ajax</h2><br />
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="text" id="tags" class="form-control" data-role="tagsinput" />
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="button" name="search" class="btn btn-primary" id="search">Search</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <div align="right">
     <p><b>Total Records - <span id="total_records"></span></b></p>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Customer Name</th>
       <th>Gender</th>
       <th>Address</th>
       <th>City</th>
       <th>Postal Code</th>
       <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <br />
  
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
 </body>
</html>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 load_data();

 function load_data(query)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#total_records').text(data.length);
    var html = '';
    if(data.length > 0)
    {
     for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
     {
      html += '<tr>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].CustomerName+'</td>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].Gender+'</td>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].Address+'</td>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].City+'</td>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].PostalCode+'</td>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].Country+'</td></tr>';
     }
    }
    else
    {
     html = '<tr><td colspan="5">No Data Found</td></tr>';
    }
    $('tbody').html(html);
   }
  })
 }

 $('#search').click(function(){
  var query = $('#tags').val();
  load_data(query);
 });

});
</script>
```

Fetch.php

```
    <?php

//fetch.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing", "root", "");

$output = '';

$query = '';

if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
 $search = str_replace(",", "|", $_POST["query"]);
 $query = "
 SELECT * FROM tbl_customer 
 WHERE CustomerName REGEXP '".$search."' 
 OR Address REGEXP '".$search."' 
 OR City REGEXP '".$search."' 
 OR PostalCode REGEXP '".$search."' 
 OR Country REGEXP '".$search."'
 ";
}
else
{
 $query = "
 SELECT * FROM tbl_customer ORDER BY CustomerID
 ";
}

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();

while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
 $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: If you check in your browser console you might be getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null` . Because no result are there you are trying to print `$('#total_records').text(data.length);`  put that part inside `if(data.length)...` and see onces

Comment: Yes, you are right, Unacught type error saw in my browser. Can you help me how to put that line . I still not getting in by putting . if(data.length > 0)
  $('#total_records').text(data.length);

Comment: put in the top of fetch.php  $data = [];  so this var is always present en will be returned to your javascript

Comment: Thanks @IvoP . It works, but it does not show error message under the html table . Acutally, this {
     html = '<tr><td colspan="5">No Data Found</td></tr>';
    } still not worked. any idea?

Comment: Check what does `data` has inside success function when no matching result found i.e: `alert(data)`

Comment: In that case it is an empty array. So I expect data.length to be equal to 0.

Comment: I think adding $data=[] in fetch.php is the solution to this question.

Comment: Thanks IvoP and Swati for the answers. Appreciated. It is resolved now.

Comment: @IvoP , when I search something on that search box and press enter, it does not search. Searching with enter button not working . I tried changed <button> tag inside type=''submit" , but not working. Please help.

Comment: you start a search by "('#search').click(function() {". So a Click on the button with id="search" should start s.  If you want other ways to start it, you should add events, like "on submit, on keyup and check for keycode 13 etc)

Comment: Hi, @IvoP , i need to add the new codes under this line or need to edit?  ' $('#search').click(function(){
  var query = $('#tags').val(); 
  load_data(query);
 }); I have tried and read but still not get it. is it because of the multi search box?

Comment: @IvoP please check this link for demo. http://demo.webslesson.info/bootstrap-tags-input-with-php/ . is it possible to search with enter?

Comment: you could do $('.bootstrap-tagsinput').on('keyup', function(e) { if(e.which == 13} { $('#search').trigger('click' });

Comment: please note: the bar containing those tags already responds to "enter" in order to add those tag-fields to the bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as future reference my answer in more than 1 comment line:

In Fetch.php the variable $data will only exist in the case one or more answers are found.
otherwise, the var $data is still not present at the last line: json_encode($data);
Would you have your error_reporting on, it would give you a message about "undefined var data on line X".

PHP will forgive you, and suppose $data has value NULL; So you get a json_encoded form or NULL.

So if you put in the top of your Fetch.php  it will always exist and be an empty or a filled array.

This will avoid your error in Javascript where you cannot read the length of NULL.
An empty array however has length = 0.